# I want bootstrap bradning below navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I had this looking okay, but after implementing other changes, the problem seems to be returning.

Please see attached pic that goes with the following description:

What I would like to do is to have the navbar for my home page at the top and have my logo just beneath it and all the way to the left. That is, I do not want the nav bar overlapping the logo as it currently does.

I have also included my code below. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
 [![<body>   

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- nav navbar-nav -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li class="dropdown" >
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown" role="menu" data-toggle="dropdown" >Log In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <!--<div class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">-->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <form action="login.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="username">Username</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" />
                              <label for="password">Password</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" />
                              <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--container-fluid-->
</nav>

<section class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <section class="branding" >          
                <a href="index.php"><img src="/projectx/images/logo1.png" alt="Logo For Project X"></a>             
                <span style="color:red; float:right; margin-top:4%; margin-right: 4%; border: 3px black solid; padding: 3%">        
                </span>
            </section>
            </div>          
</section><!-- branding -->

<!--
<div class="brand"> <a href="#"><img src="images/logo1.png"></a></div>
--> 
<section class="sidebar col col-lg-4">

</section><!-- sidebar -->

    <section class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <!--<section class="branding">           
                <a href="index.php"><img src="/projectx/images/logo1.png" alt="Logo For Project X"></a>             

            </section>-->
            </div>

    </section><!-- branding -->

</section><!--sidebar-->

</body>][1]][1]
```

Comment: do you have the required padding on the body? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-navbar-fixed-top-padding

Comment: I had this done with bootstrap before (with no padding added to the body), I just can't remember how I did it. Or at least I thought. I will take a look at the link however. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is ultimately what you're trying to do: create a sidebar for the logo to rest inside and scroll with the fixed navbar.

```css
body,
html,
.row-offcanvas {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu form .form-group .form-control,
.navbar .dropdown-menu form .form-group label,
.navbar .dropdown-menu form .form-group .btn-primary {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.sidebar-fixed {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*background: lightgrey;*/
}
.sidebar-fixed img {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
.main-content {
  /*background: lightblue;*/
  margin-left: 110px;
  padding: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .navbar .dropdown-menu form .form-group {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .sidebar-fixed {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-content {
    /*background: lightblue; */
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
              <form action="login.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" />
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" />
                  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" />
                </div>
              </form>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="sidebar-fixed">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/67A7CA/fff?text=logo" />
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="well well-primary">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
      up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.</div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Sidebar Warning</div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first
          line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This
          book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de
          Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
          from a line in section 1.10.32. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular
          during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```